# Comparison between d3.js and chart.js (only for charts)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, chart.js

I have used chart.js in my projects several times but I have never used d3.js. A lot of people say that d3.js is the best javascript framework for charts but none of them is able to explain why, especially when I want a comparison to chart.js.

I have found this: http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-charting-comparison/
but it is not what I was looking for.

Does anyone know about a comparison of these frameworks in terms of usability and performance (only for charts)?

Comment: Just for fun, I am developing chart.js basic charts using d3.js with same dataset.

You can take a look  - https://s.codepen.io/bumbeishvili/debug/RGbvPg

Comment: Update 2018 d3 has canvas too

Answer (score 238, accepted):

**`d3.js` is not a "charting" library.**  It is a library for creating and manipulating SVG/HTML.  It provides tools to help you visualize and manipulate your data.  While you can use it to create conventional charts (bar, line, pie, etc.) it's capable of so much more.  Of course with this "capable of so much" comes a steeper learning curve.   There are a lot of conventional charting libraries built on top of `d3.js` - `nvd3.js`, `dimple.js`, `dc.js` if you want to go that route.

I'm not familiar with `Chart.js` but a quick look at the website tells me it's more of a run-of-the-mill charting library.  It supports 6 basic chart types and you aren't ever going to do [stuff](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006) [like](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1353700) [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) [with](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) [it](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426).  **But** the API looks straightforward and I'm sure it's easy to use.

The most obvious distinction between the two is that `Chart.js` is canvas-based, while `d3.js` is mainly about SVG.  (Now I say *mainly* because `d3.js` can manipulate all types of HTML elements so [you could even use it](http://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas/) to help you draw on a canvas.)  In general, canvas will outperform SVG for many elements (I'm talking huge - thousands of points, lines, etc...).

SVG, on the other hand, is easier to manipulate and interact with.  With SVG each point, line, etc becomes part of the DOM - you want that point green now, just change it.  With canvas it's a static drawing that was to be redrawn to make any change - of course, it draws so fast you'll usually never notice.  Here's [some good reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg193983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: @emrah, the link may be old (around the time of IE9) but the information provided is still very much relevant.

Answer (score 43):

Since I am trying to find a fast charting library to show charts on mobile devices, performance was important for me. It also had to have a licence that makes it possible to use commercially. I compared:

1. c3, which is based on d3 and therefore uses SVG
2. chart.js which is using canvas

The charts are loaded inside a WebView component inside a native app and all data (including the JS library) is local, so no slow down due to http requests. To maximize performance even more, I additionally put everything inside one single file.

I loaded 4 charts (line, bar, pie, line/bar combo) with together around 500 datapoints.

My time measuring exluded the actual loading of the html page. I measured form the moment I started using the charting library code until the end of rendering. All chart animation was turned off.

C3 took around 1500-1800 ms on modern Android and IPhone devices. iPhone performed around 100ms better than Android.

Chart.js took around 400-800ms. Android performed around 300ms better than iPhone.

No surprise, the SVG is slower. Depending on your use case, maybe too slow.

On a desktop computer rendering in c3 was around 150-200ms and charts.js around 80-100ms. Running the same test in Android and iPhone emulator had the same result as on desktop. So the slow down on mobile devices is definitely due to hardware/processing limits.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATED 2016**

The general rule of thumb is:

`d3.js` - great for interactive visualizations

`chart.js` - great for quick and simple

[A few other charting libraries](http://stackshare.io/stackups/highcharts-vs-d3-vs-c3) are on the rise, so keep testing and don't forget to contribute to the [open source](https://github.com/d3/d3)!

Answer (score 1):

  **chart.js**
- It uses html5 canvas tag which is pixel dependent ,so when you resize the chart.js generated graph you loose clarity
- It is declarative, means you have to just declare required inputs to generate graph
- Learning curve is less
- Types of charts generated are predefined and limited

  **d3.js**
- It uses svg which is resolution independent,so when you resize the d3 generated graph you will not loose clarity
- It is imperative, means you have to write some logic to generate charts
- Steep learning curve
- Types of charts generated are not predefined and you can create any chart you want