# D3.js: Bars in Bar chart, scales are not modeling data properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

https://codepen.io/juanf03/pen/YGyyjY?editors=1111

I'm modeling a bar chart with D3.js and the data is not being represented by the bars like it's supossed to be....this would be the correct chart

[image]

And this is my chart:

[image]

For some reason my scales doesn't seem to be right...I ordered the data by GDP with lodash and that seems to be correct on the console. The json contains the GDP of the year and the year itself. Does anyone see a problem setting my scales?. This is my .js file.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json';

  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  //build svg with class chart
  var width=800, height=600, padding=50;
  var  canvas=d3.select('#holder').append('svg').attr('id','chart').style({"width":width,"height":height}).attr('transform','translate(' + padding + ',' + padding + ')');;


  d3.json(url, function( data ) {
  let datausa=_.sortBy(data.data,1),barWidth=Math.ceil(width/data.data.length);
 console.log(datausa);
    var svg = d3.select("svg");
console.log(datausa);
d3.select(".notes").append("text").text(data.description);

  var maxMinYearSet=d3.extent(datausa,function(d){
      return d[0].substring(0,4);
  });


  //build x scale, year
  var xScale=d3.time.scale()
  .range([0,width])
  .domain(maxMinYearSet);

  //build y scale, gross dom prod

  var maxY=d3.max(datausa,function(d){
    return d[1];
  });

  var yScale=d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,maxY])
  .range([height-padding,0]);


   //set up the x axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
                             .orient("bottom")
                             .ticks(20);

   //set up the y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
                             .orient("left")
                             .ticks(20);


         // Add the X Axis
      canvas.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      canvas.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);


  var rect= canvas.selectAll('rect.rectangle')
             .data(datausa)
             .enter()
             .append('rect').attr('class','rectangle');

 rect.attr('x',function(d,i){
  return i*barWidth;
});

 rect.attr('y',function(d){
  return 0;
}); 

rect.attr('height',function(d){
  return yScale(d[1]);
});  

rect.attr('width',function(d){
  return 20;
}); 

rect.on("mouseover", function(d){
  console.log(d3.select(this));

});

rect.on("mouseleave",function(d){

});


});


});
```

this is my html file:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="title">
    US Gross Domestic Product by quarter
    </id>
  <div id="holder">


  </div> 
   <div class="notes">

      </div>

</div>
```

and my css:

```
#holder{
  border: 1px black solid;

}

.rectangle{
  fill:#0097A7;
  margin:10px;
}

svg{
   /*-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform:scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);*/
}
```

The chart is upside down as well, is there anyway of correcting that without using css transform?.....Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `height` and `y` calculations are off.  If you refer to the [venerable bar chart example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), it should be:

```
  rect.attr('y', function(d) {
    return  yScale(d[1]);
  });

  rect.attr('height', function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d[1]);
  });
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <script data-require="lodash.js@4.16.2" data-semver="4.16.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.js"></script>
  <style>
    #holder {
      border: 1px black solid;
    }
    
    .rectangle {
      fill: #0097A7;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    svg {
      /*-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform:scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);*/
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="title">
      US Gross Domestic Product by quarter
    </div>
    <div id="holder"></div>
    <div class="notes"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json';

    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    //build svg with class chart
    var width = 800,
      height = 600,
      padding = 50;
    var canvas = d3.select('#holder').append('svg').attr('id', 'chart').style({
      "width": width,
      "height": height
    }).attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ',' + padding + ')');;


    d3.json(url, function(data) {
      let datausa = _.sortBy(data.data, 1),
        barWidth = Math.ceil(width / data.data.length);
      console.log(datausa);
      var svg = d3.select("svg");
      console.log(datausa);
      d3.select(".notes").append("text").text(data.description);

      var maxMinYearSet = d3.extent(datausa, function(d) {
        return d[0].substring(0, 4);
      });


      //build x scale, year
      var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain(maxMinYearSet);

      //build y scale, gross dom prod

      var maxY = d3.max(datausa, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      });

      var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxY])
        .range([height - padding, 0]);


      //set up the x axis
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(20);

      //set up the y axis
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(20);


      // Add the X Axis
      canvas.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      canvas.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);


      var rect = canvas.selectAll('rect.rectangle')
        .data(datausa)
        .enter()
        .append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle');

      rect.attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return i * barWidth;
      });

      rect.attr('y', function(d) {
        return  yScale(d[1]);
      });

      rect.attr('height', function(d) {
        return height - yScale(d[1]);
      });

      rect.attr('width', function(d) {
        return 20;
      });

      rect.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log(d3.select(this));

      });

      rect.on("mouseleave", function(d) {

      });


    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's not working :S, not showing any graphics  https://codepen.io/juanf03/pen/YGyyjY?editors=1111

Comment: the bars are not showing, only the Y axis.....run your code snippet and you will see....

Comment: @Juan, it's working for me.  Please try it again.  I loaded `lodash` over `http`, so if you visit stackoverflow as `https`, it's possible the snippet wasn't running correctly.

Comment: could you share it on a codepen whenever you can?. I can't see the bars either with http nor https

Comment: @juan, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HJfHysXiDzqbAHDZVpFw?p=preview).  Do you get any errors in the console?  I'm really scratching my head about why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: No errors, I just see the Y axis with no bars on the graphic.....Here's the screenshot of what I see

https://postimg.org/image/uuihyjhvf/

This library is the hardest one I had to use....I'm planning to take another course on D3 on egghead to get better....

Comment: @Juan, really digging into this you have lots of troubles.  How you set up your axis and padding is a little strange.  Also, you x-axis is a time scale but you are giving it strings (it needs dates...).  Further, you then build the x component of the bars not with that date, just with the index.  You are really missing some fundamental concepts here.  Give me a few and I'll post an update and attempt to clean up the plot.

Comment: that would be great, thanks!. I just need one good example to keep creating other charts and learn by doing cause this is really hard to tackle down on my own and I can't seem to find quality examples for my specific needs....is it supossed to have this steep learning curve?

Comment: @Jaun, Yes, `d3` has a steep learning curve.  Read what I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27348187/16363).  Essentially, d3 isn't a plotting library, it's a library for data visualizations.  It's capable of so much that and so much more === harder to learn.

Comment: @Juan, [here's your plot all fixed up](http://plnkr.co/edit/eYJV1v40I6OOAUyV3ajf?p=preview).

Comment: that worked wonders mark, thank you very much, I will work on this to try to understand every step....after this I have to build a plotting map so this will come really handy